# how to create a list with stateful components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react, and I have this problem that when trying to map an array to a list of React stateful component, all my components lose their state. My code:

```js
const { useState, useEffect} = React;

const htmlRoot = document.getElementById('root');
const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(htmlRoot);

const App = () => {
    const Item = (props) => {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        useEffect(() => {
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                setCount((lastCount) => lastCount + 1);
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(timer);
        }, []);
        return <h1>{props.children + ' ' + count}</h1>;
    };

    const arr = [1, 2, 3];
    const [arrState, setArrState] = useState(arr);
    const clickHandler = () => {
        setArrState((lastArrState) => [
            ...lastArrState,
            lastArrState.at(-1) + 1,
        ]);
    };
    return (
        // Unfortunately, Stack Snippets don't support the shorthand form
        // of fragments
        <React.Fragment>
            {arrState.map((num, index) => (
                <Item key={index}>{num}</Item>
            ))}
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

reactRoot.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Is this even possible for them to keep their state? If it is, how?
Update:

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "they lose their state"?  What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, here on SO, we don't edit solutions into questions; I've removed that for you. It may be worth taking the [tour] (you get a badge!), having a look around, and reading through the [help]. :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder I sure will. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a **new** `Item` component every time your `App` component is called to render. Since the subsequent renders are using **different** components that previous renders, React gets rid of the previous instances and creates new ones with fresh state.

Instead, define your `Item` component *outside* `App` and then use it within:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const htmlRoot = document.getElementById('root');
const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(htmlRoot);

const Item = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCount((lastCount) => lastCount + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);
    return <h1>{props.children + ' ' + count}</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3];
    const [arrState, setArrState] = useState(arr);
    const clickHandler = () => {
        setArrState((lastArrState) => [
            ...lastArrState,
            lastArrState.at(-1) + 1,
        ]);
    };
    return (
        // (Sadly, Stack Snippets don't support the shorthand form
        // of fragments.)
        <React.Fragment>
            {arrState.map((num, index) => (
                <Item key={index}>{num}</Item>
            ))}
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

reactRoot.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

Separately, don't use `index` for `key` (unless the list is static or ever-growing and never reordered — yours fits that latter category, but I'm guessing at some point you'll remove items from it). Details about why [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [the article it links to](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/). Instead, ensure the things being listed have some form of unique, reusable identifier.